# delete top margin from Customizr theme's web page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a WordPress newbie.
I am running my website on Customizr-Child theme (using Child Themify plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/child-themify/).
When, I try to write html code in a webpage, there seem to be unnecessary margin at the top of the page, ex. http://www.resourcematics.com/ag-tool/
I would like to get rid of this top margin.

My Child theme Appearance > editor tab has only style.css file.

Can somebody guide me please how to resolve this issue!
Thanks in advance,
Ankit

Comment: Do you mean the full width green bar at the top?

Comment: Thanks. No I meant the space between page title 'Ag tool' and the body text "....Our GIS based agriculture water demand...."

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you reset your css code by adding this in the top of it

```
* {
   margin : 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

If you did that, and the margin is still there, make sure there isn't any `<h1>` or `<h2>` in the top of your code , because they have default margin that appear like it's `body` margin-top

If there is any try to make a class for them called for example `title`
then add this to your css file

```
.title {
   margin : 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: He is using WordPress therefore this will not work.  The theme should have a CSS reset built into it anyways.  You have to use your browser and find out which property is making this happen and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually not a margin but a border.

```
 .tc-header {  
border-bottom: 10px solid #e9eaee;
border-top: 5px solid #27cda5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. No I meant the space between page title 'Ag tool' and the body text "....Our GIS based agriculture water demand...."

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

So, in light of the clarification regarding the issue, here's what I found out by opening up the browser developer inspector tool. Look at the HTML which is generated in your content container:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>
        <br><br><br>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- P tag with line break BR tags and meta tag -->
    </p>

    <p>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><br>
        <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js"></script>
        <!-- P tag with meta tag and script tag -->
    </p>
    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        .map-info { font-size: 20px; }
        #map { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 500px; }
    </style>

    <p>
        <br>
        <!-- P tag with line break BR tag -->
    </p>

    <div>
        Our GIS based agriculture water demand model is of 5 X 5 arc minutes (approximately 9 X 9   kilometres at the equator) resolution.
    </div>

    <p>
        Following maps show <b>area irrigated by country in hectares around year 2010</b>. The map was developed based on <a href="http://www.uni-frankfurt.de/45218039/Global_Irrigation_Map">Siebert <i>et. al.</i>, 2005</a> and Resourcematics’ Agriculture Water Model
    </p>
</div>
```

What conclusions can we draw about this? Simple.

1. **P tags**: Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each P tag element. [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_p.asp)
2. **BR tags** (inside P tags): Pretty much self-explanatory. Adds a line-break.
3. **The Plugin that generates the map**: It seems that the plugin adds all it's scripts, css and responsive meta (just like you would in the HEAD section of a html page) directly in your content container. He does so by enclosing it's content in our aforementioned P tags (it's a big guess, but plausible).

Solution(s):

- If I were you, I would check first if, by accident, you added
  unnecessary line breaks in the WYSIWYG editor before the main text.
- I would consider maybe using and testing out other Map plugins and
  see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks. No I meant the space between page title 'Ag tool' and the body text "....Our GIS based agriculture water demand...."

Comment: @Ankit Just edited my post in light of new specifications. Get back to me if this makes sense

Comment: thanks for clarification. My html code works fine (without any space at the top) in http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_paragraphs1.  I follow you, after using Firebug in Firefox. I could remove P-tags and BR-tags in Firebug and seems to work on web page by removing top margin. But I don't know, how to do the same in actual wordpress website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said, I suspect the Map plugin to cause the problem. You would need to login to the admin panel of the wordpress and try out other map plugins. Of course it depends if is actually a plugin you are using or if the map code is pasted directly in the Text editor.

Comment: Thanks. I've pasted html code directly into text editor of my web page. Map plugin is unlikely to cause the issue, as the code works fine in online html editors. The top-margin appears only in web page. So I guess, it is the web template of WordPress. I've also tried the same web page in different WordPress themes (e.g. twenty twelve, twenty thirteen), but top margin remains. Thanks.